# SELECT does not return rows when queried by VBELN

Tags: abap, opensql

I'm trying to display table in alv from an internal table where rows are added form a table stored in the database. Without a where condition I see rows displayed in alv but with a where condition in the select statement no rows are returned.

Here is the code:

```
REPORT  ZSAM.

DATA: IT_1 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF VBAK.

select vbeln audat netwr waerk vkorg vtweg 
    from VBAK 
    into corresponding fields of Table IT_1 
    where vbeln > 4500 
      and vbeln < 6000.
```

Any idea why using where condition makes it not return any rows and how to fix?

Comment: Please reduce your question to the minimal problem. If you debug right after the first `SELECT`, you will see that `IT_1` is empty, so the issue is not about ALV and you don't need to show the code about ALV (no need to talk about ALV at all).

Comment: Yah, I think it is better now, Cannot figure out why no rows are returned or appended to IT_1

Comment: Thank you. I have again reduced the code because the output of the SELECT result is not concerned by the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vbeln is a field with ten positions and uses `ALPHA` conversion routine (see the domain behind the data element). This means the value is filled with leading zeros (as long as it does contain numbers only). As this is a character type field, you also have to use apostrophes for the comparison. So, the `WHERE` condition has to be like this:

```
WHERE vbeln GT '0000004500'
  AND vbeln LT '0000006000'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use range;

**First usage;**

DATA: r_vbeln TYPE RANGE OF vbeln.

DATA: s_vbeln LIKE LINE OF r_vbeln.

s_vbeln-option = 'BT'.

s_vbeln-sign   = 'I'.

s_vbeln-low    = '0000004501'.

s_vbeln-high   = '0000005999'.

APPEND s_vbeln TO r_vbeln.

SELECT condition; *WHERE vbeln IN r_vbeln.*

**Second usage;**

DATA: r_vbeln TYPE RANGE OF vbeln.

DATA: s_vbeln LIKE LINE OF r_vbeln.

s_vbeln-option = 'GT'.

s_vbeln-sign   = 'I'.

s_vbeln-low    = '0000004500'.

APPEND s_vbeln TO r_vbeln.

s_vbeln-option = 'LT'.

s_vbeln-sign   = 'I'.

s_vbeln-low    = '0000006000'.

APPEND s_vbeln TO r_vbeln.

SELECT condition; *WHERE vbeln IN r_vbeln.*

Comment: While this may be an answer to OP's problem, code-only answers are [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow. Please consider adding some explanation to the code provided as it will benefit both OP and future visitors.